# How to correctly display a SQL Table into synchronized ComboBox and how to modify a Combobox.text only to a SQL Table cell value

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, combobox

I believe this kind of question is the silly kind but after having done some internet searching and tried a lot of solutions, I applied on this amazing forum to ask you for some help :-)

I'm trying to make an army builder list program for a historical miniatures strategy game.

I'm using VB.NET because I had some VB6 notions but as I understand I'm a VB.NET complete newbie, I can switch to C# for example. I believe my knowledge will be the same (near 0).

Here is how I try to handle it :

- There are 300 army lists in this game. I want to create 300 SQL tables which whill include every list units information like the name, shortname, type, quality and cost.
- After that, I want to "read" these tables and to put the result into several comboboxes (or textboxes but I believe the combobox control is more adapted to this ?) in order to allow the users to "browse" the available units.
- I want all the comboboxes to be synchronized in order to display the same row information.
- Concerning the "quality" combobox, I want it to "read" the qualité_unit cells value and after a comparizon to the quality_combobox value, just change it to the right value without changing the dropdownlist (which should be "free" to change by the user)

Here is a table example :
[image: Here is a table example :]

Here is a program screenshot example
[image: Here is a program screenshot example]

Here is a program screenshot example with the loaded table
[image: Here is a program screenshot example with the loaded table]

I did that with this potato code but I'm 100% sure that this is not the good way to do it :)

```
 Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sqlquery As String
    Dim bs1 As New BindingSource

    connection.Open()

    sqlquery = "select * from liste1"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    bs1.DataSource = dt

    Dim SQL As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


    While SQL.Read

        ComboBoxNomUnités.DataSource = bs1
        ComboBoxNomUnités.DisplayMember = SQL("nom_unité")
        ComboBoxNomUnités.ValueMember = "nom_unité"

        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DataSource = bs1
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DisplayMember = SQL("type_unité")
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.ValueMember = "type_unité"

        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DataSource = bs1
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DisplayMember = SQL("abréviation_unité")
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.ValueMember = "abréviation_unité"

        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DataSource = bs1
        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DisplayMember = SQL("cout_unité")
        ComboBoxCoutTotal.ValueMember = "cout_unité"
```

- And for the "quality" unit value checking, I tried something like this but of course, it's not working :

```
 Dim S As String
            S = SQL("qualité_unité").ToString

If S.Contains("médiocre") Then
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "médiocre"
            ElseIf S.Contains("élite") Then
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "élite"
            Else
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "ordinaire"
            End If
```

Anyway, many thanks for any help :)

I'm willing to learn even if I'm a total beginner...

EDIT :
Here is the solution to my first problem, provided by jdweng

```
 Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sqlquery As String


        connection.Open()

        sqlquery = "select * from liste1 Order By index_unité"


        Dim SQL As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, connection)
        SQL.Fill(dt)


        ComboBoxNomUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxNomUnités.DisplayMember = "nom_unité"

        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DisplayMember = "type_unité"

        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DisplayMember = "abréviation_unité"

        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DisplayMember = "cout_unité"


        connection.Close()
```

Comment: The results from a database may not be ordered.  So add an OrderBy to your query : "select * from liste1 OrderBy index_unite"

Comment: Well, thank you jdweng. That's a start. I'll do this !

Comment: EDIT : It generates a new error :
Pointing on:
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

and here is the error message:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'Incorrect Syntax to 'index_unité'.'

Comment: Order By is two words.  See following for syntax :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, I figured it out but I still have an error :
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'Text, ntext and image data types cannot be compared or classified except when using the LIKE or IS NULL operator.'

Comment: I believe this has to do with the table structure. Everything is in "text" into SQL Server. Should I change this ?

Comment: Try the query "select * from liste1 Order By index_unite" in SQL Server Management Studio where the error messages are much better.

Comment: Well, there is more or less the same message :
Error source : .Net sqlClient Data Provider 
Error Message : text, ntext and image cannot be compared or classified except when using the LIKE or IS NULL operator.

Comment: What are the column types?  Do you get same error without Order By?  A column of type nvar or number should compare without issues.  So I suspect you may have some other types.  The documentation says nulls should be order first in the results.  So I'm confused.

Comment: Columns type were text. I changed them to nchar(10) and I don't have the SQL error anymore. But now, I've a VB Error concerning the ComboBox.valuemember.

It says : System.argumentException : "Bind to the new display member impossible"
Parameter name : newDisplayMember

I tried nvarchar(50) and it's the same error

Comment: See following code.  You need a DataAdapter : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/programmatically-binding-datasource-to-combobox-in-multiple/

Comment: You mean a SqlDataAdapter instead of a SqlDataReader ?

Comment: Yes. See sample code. The Adapter is used to fill a DataTable.  You are using : dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and let you know :-)

Comment: It's working, big thanks jdweng.

I'm editing the post with the solution to my first issue :-)
 
Now, I'd like to compare the "qualité_unité" columns cells value (see my original post :-))

Comment: I believe I have to use SqlDataReader 

I tried :
`
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

 reader.Read()

        If reader("qualité_unité").ToString = "médiocre" Then
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "médiocre"
            ElseIf reader("qualité_unité").ToString = "élite" Then
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "élite"
            Else
                ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = "ordinaire"
            End If
`
But for some reason, it's not working

Comment: Well, I'll create a new topic to solve my other problem, it will be more understandable :-)

Thanks a lot jdweng for the SqlDataAdapter tip

Answer (score 0):

Provided by jdweng

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sqlquery As String


        connection.Open()

        sqlquery = "select * from liste1 Order By index_unité"


        Dim SQL As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, connection)
        SQL.Fill(dt)


        ComboBoxNomUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxNomUnités.DisplayMember = "nom_unité"

        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DisplayMember = "type_unité"

        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DisplayMember = "abréviation_unité"

        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DisplayMember = "cout_unité"


        connection.Close()
```